# Point charge between two infinite dielectrics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, dielectric

Two infinite linear homogeneous and isotropic dielectrics $\epsilon_1$ , $\epsilon_2$, occupy the regions $z>0$ , $z<0$ respectively. A point charge q is located at the origin. By applying the appropriate boundary conditions, prove that the potential is of the form $V(r)$ (where $r$ is the distance from the point charge) and find its expression everywhere.

I have tried everything but the only solution i have come up with is with the method of images (at the limit where the point charge approaches the separation surface $D\rightarrow 0$). Obviously this is not the method that the problem wants me to use, so its no good.

Comment: If there is any work that you've tried, it's best if you include it to give us a sense of how you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Source of the claim that potential is function of $r$ only? This is hard to believe, as the different polarizability of two half-spaces will result in a charge distribution that is not spherically symmetrical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following, all expressions are expressed in terms of the spherical coordinate system.

Recall the electrostatic formula for a point charge q in a vacuum, not a dielectric.
\begin{align*}
V(r)&=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r}\tag{1}, \\
\vec{E}(r)&=-\frac{dV(r)}{dr}\vec{e}_r=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r^2}\vec{e}_r\tag{2},
\end{align*}
where $q$ is electric point charge, $V(r)$ is electric scalar potential,
$\epsilon_0$ is the permitivity of vacuum,
$\vec{E}(r)$ is electric field and $\vec{e}_r$ is unit vector.

Equations (1) and (2) are also the answers when different dielectric materials
are placed at $z>0$ and $z<0$, as in the problem setup.
However, unlike the vacuum case, in the presence of a dielectric, q is not a given known quantity, but an unknown quantity to be determined later.

To confirm that it is a solution, we can find it by calculating the $\vec{D}$ field, i.e.,
the electric flux density vector:
\begin{align*}
\vec{D}(r)=\frac{\epsilon_1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r^2}\vec{e}_r\;(\text{for }z>0)\tag{3}, \\
\vec{D}(r)=\frac{\epsilon_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r^2}\vec{e}_r\;(\text{for }z<0)\tag{4}.
\end{align*}
Note that $\text{div}\vec{D}=0\;{\text provided}\; r\neq 0$.
The total amount of electric charge at the center becomes the following equation using Gauss's law,
\begin{equation*}
\text{total charge}=Q=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2}{\epsilon_0}q\tag{5}
\end{equation*}
If $Q$ is given, then we can calculate $q$ using (5). And substituting this $q$ value into (1), (2), (3) and (4) we get the solution.

Comment: I think that the charge $q$ used in equations (3) and (4) reffers to the "effective" charge due to dielectric screening. The free charge (i.e. the point charge) in this case is symbolized as $Q$. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @Manos total charge (including the polarization charge) in this answer is $q$, because (3),(4) imply electric field is the Coulomb field due to $q$. I don't know what $Q$ is.

Comment: Ah yes, $Q$ is the free charge at the center, and $q$ is total charge including the polarization charge.

Comment: In (3),(4), you seem to assume electric field that implies the only charge is the total charge $q$ at the center. But what if there is a polarization charge on the boundary, due to possible discontinuity of electric field there?

Comment: I was going to think about it and then comment, but as the thread is about to be closed and deleted, I will hastily include only the part that completes the meaning of my sentence.
Q is the total free (true) charge, the value is someone specified, a given value.
On the other hand, q has the same unit of electric charge, but it is not any charge, just a parameter describing the solution.
Regarding the question "..., due to possible discontinuity of electric field there?", sorry I have not thought about this question at the moment.